# How can I QuickCheck Arbitary functions

Tags: haskell

I am quite new on Haskell and I was trying to chek a fuction of mine.
The funktion is in type of

```
treeValidate :: forall a. Ord a => BST a -> Bool
```

How could I validate this? I tried quickChekc treeValidate but I get this error: • No instance for (Arbitrary (BST a0))
arising from a use of ‘quickCheck’

edit fixed a typo on the error message

Comment: You make `BST` (`BHP`) an instance of `Arbitrary`.

Comment: Yes, but how is it typed on the quickCheck? I tried : quickChekc (treeValidate :: BST Int -> Bool) but that does not wor either.

Comment: What is the `BST` datatype?

Comment: Its a binary search tree

Comment: Once you write an `Arbitrary` instance like the existing answers recommend, to use `quickCheck` you need to think about what properties you want to test. `quickCheck (\ t -> treeValidate (t :: BST Int))` only checks that all of the trees generated by the `Arbitrary` instance are valid according to `treeValidate`, but you probably want to generate valid trees in the `Arbitrary` instance, and then use `treeValidate` to test other functions; e.g. if you have a function `insert`, use `quickCheck $ \ x t -> treeValidate $ insert (x :: Int) (t :: BST Int)` to verify that `insert` preserves validity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [write an `Aribtrary` instance](https://www.stackbuilders.com/news/a-quickcheck-tutorial-generators) for your type.

Answer (score 2):

@WillemVanOnsem said you need an Arbitrary instance.  You responded "Yes, but how is it typed on the quickCheck?".

I don't understand your response question.  The fact is, you must write:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (BST a) where
    arbitrary = -- your code here
```

Where `your code here` is the definition of arbitrary you write to generate arbitrary (random) values of type `BST a`.